# C# Windows Forms subclass of generic parameter Form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, inheritance

I have a windows Form called "Selektor" with a data grid view element and some menu bar controls. The class header is

```
Selektor<T> : Form where T : Table
```

For different Table-subclasses I need different buttons on the menu bar. I thought about creating a sub-class of Selektor, where I can add different menu bars for different sub classes of Table. For some reason my sub class with header

```
public partial class Form1<T> : Selektor<T>
```

The compiler tells me: "Type T cannot be used as type parameter T in generic type or method "Selector ".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a constraint on the T type for the Selektor class:

```
Selektor<T> : Form where T : Table
```

but then you are not using the same constraint in this declaration:

```
public partial class Form1<T> : Selektor<T>
```

as if every generic type T is good for Form1, but hey, Selektor can't have a T not derived from Table. With this definition it's possible to write something like:

```
new Form1<Other>()
```

feeding the base class Selektor a type it can't accept.

You should use:

```
public partial class Form1<T> : Selektor<T> where T : Table
```